# What is right datatype with numbers along with '-'

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I know it might sound silly, I have to look up MySQL manual reference and another MySQL forum. as I could not find what is right datatype for numbers with '-' e.g

'405-6444235-1711500'

I'm not sure this number datatype like TINYINT, SMALLINT, MEDIUMINT INT and BIGINT will not working on this.
I'm not sure if varchar is a right choice for this.

So Any Suggest what is the right choice for this before I build a new table and Data await to upload it.

Comment: yes, This "part" will be used together as not separate. this function might be useful for data record in some stage later but not now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With hyphens, it's a string, full stop!

You could store it as a BIGINT (without the hyphens) and format it using the hyphens on the client side - putting hyphens at 4 and 12.

However, if the position of the hyphens varies, you'll have to store it as a string and not any form of number.

You should only store values as numbers if you're going to add/subtract/multiply or divide them - otherwise, they are strings and not "numbers" anyway! How do you perform mathematical operations with "numbers" which have hyphens?

Comment: Thanks for your help, I was not sure what it called, it was hyphens.

Comment: Can also be called "dashes" - depending on where you're from - "dash" might be more North American.

Comment: Yes, I was going said dash but I am not sure if it's correct one! so i decided to put '-' rather than dashes

Comment: Here's a deadly [image](http://karwin.blogspot.ie/2009/05/eav-fail.html) which illustrates the point about  mathematical operations :-)